# Trouble changing Nickname in Discord.js, giving me DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm having trouble allowing the user change their server nickname with the bot command.

```
  if (msg.content.startsWith("newName")) {
    nickname = msg.content.split("newName ")[1]
    if (!nickname)return msg.reply("Add a name for the new nickname")

    msg.member.setNickname(nickname)

    msg.channel.send(`Your new nickname has been set as **${nickname}**`)
  }
```

I keep getting this error even though I have given the bot permission to manage and change nicknames in the server.

```
(node:661) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute
```

(node:661) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`

Comment: Where is the bot's highest role placed in relating to the member? An error can still occure if the bot's role is under the member's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the owner of the Guild the bot will not be able to change your Nickname. If not Make sure the bot has the Manage Nicknames permission and that the person the bot is trying to change the nickname of is under the highest role the bot has.